# SonarQube, Fargate & AWS ElasticSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, sonarqube, aws-fargate, aws-elasticsearch

I’m running SonarQube 7.9 LTS Community. I am hosting it on AWS using Fargate, RDS and it’s working. I’d like to however switch from using the inbuilt SonarQube ElasticSearch to the AWS ElasticSearch.

Is this possible when using the Community Edition? I ask because essentially what I am trying to setup is pretty much the DataCenter edition as described here https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/install-cluster/. It states " Running SonarQube as a Cluster is only possible with a Data Center Edition ."

I am not really looking for high availability. It just isn’t good practice to run ElasticSearch within a Fargate container as the Elasticsearch indexes will be deleted whenever the container is replaced.

In addition to the above the SonarQube doco states:
" By default, Elasticsearch data is stored in $SONARQUBE-HOME/data , but this is not recommended for production instances. Instead, you should store this data elsewhere, ideally in a dedicated volume with fast I/O. Beyond maintaining acceptable performance, doing so will also ease the upgrade of SonarQube." (https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/install-server/)

So yeah, I’d like to be able to use the AWS Elasticsearch, not the SonarQube integrated one. Is this possible?

Comment: You already stated: "not the SonarQube integrated one". You cannot activate a config switch to switch between Elasticsearch implementations. There is also a good reason why the DataCenter edtion is only available under license conditions....

Comment: There is an option to specify a search an Elasticsearch host `sonar.search.host=` (https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/7.9/sonar-application/src/main/assembly/conf/sonar.properties). The Datacenter edition settings file includes settings like `sonar.cluster.enabled=true sonar.cluster.hosts=`. So I am not trying to activate a config switch that does not exist in or magically switch to the Datacenter edition. My question above still stands.

Comment: Information about the cluster setup can be found [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/install-cluster). The usage of sonar.cluster.hosts is explained also. But this is the most important statement: "You need a dedicated license to activate the Data Center Edition. If you don't have one yet, please contact the SonarSource Sales Team."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears (see link below) you must use the ElasticSearch embedded within the SonarQube. You cannot use any third party ElasticSearch services etc.

https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-fargate-aws-elasticsearch/11576/5